# Showing .dmg EULA when updating with Sparkle Framework

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, sparkle

I always have an EULA attached to my DMGs. But my users now can only see it the first time they download my application.

Whenever they get an upgrade within the app through Sparkle framework, the EULA is not shown when the .dmg gets extracted by Sparkle. How can I make Sparkle show the EULA?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It will just annoy your users.

Comment: Well, in the case the EULA changed, it would be nice to show it again. The EULA won't change often though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since EULAs are important to you, I would recommend that you display it in your application. That way, a user could always refer to it. A simple dialog with a WebView should do the trick.

It should not take very long to write and to localize, and it's time better spent than trying to shoe-horn it into Sparkle.